# 9-patch image blurred with border

Tags: android, png, nine-patch

I've an image.jpg that i have edited in GIMP to change to a png. I have uploaded the png to the Android Assets Studio to make a 9-patch. This works ok.

[Android Assets Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)

I'm wanting 2 versions of the same image. This is because the image is used for a button, so when the user clicks the button it is reduced in size(like when you launch an app).

The problem is when i try to create the 2nd image, i scale it down by 20% in GIMP then run it through the assets studio. I have have both images in the res/drawable folders under the correct densities L - XH dpi. When the user clicks the button the scaled version has a black border around it and it seems blurred.

How can i scale and create a 9-patch correctly.

Thanks in advance.

[image: normal state]

[image: button pressed(scaled png)]

[edit]

[image: here is the original png.]

[image]

Comment: Your scaling probably messed up the border. Post the actual .9.png images and you'll get a more exact answer.

Comment: @Geobits i've edited the post. The first image is the original png, the 2nd is the scaled .9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your black bars got messed up when scaled. If you look closely at the image, you can see that there are some semi-transparent pixels at either side of a couple of them. Make sure that every non-black pixel is perfectly transparent(alpha 0).

Also, as a side note, your stretch areas(left/top bars) don't see right. Currently, it will stretch only the center of the globe, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Paint %40 opacity gray color into the button, and specify it clicked state in selector. You may use directly 9-patch editor to do this easily.

Firts make 2 buttons(normal and clicked) and convert it to 9-patch.

Check [this tutorial](http://tugrulasik.com/2013/07/14/9-patch-cizim-editorunun-kullanimi-wysiwyg-editor/) for more information.